# Workaround to Salesforce Streaming API limitations

Tags: node.js, heroku, soap, salesforce, streaming

we are looking into using Salesforce Streaming API, but two limitations jump out at us and might make it not an option.

1. The limitation for the Query to be a max of 1300 characters.

   Maximum length of the SOQL query in the Query field of a PushTopic record is 1300
2. Long Texts and not able to be streamed.
   (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/unsupported_soql_statements.htm)

How would it be possible to get around this issue? And how does Heroku Connect get by this issue?

any help would be great

Thanks